# name property of object, javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, oop

i have a question regarding name property of object, so here is a situation:
im creating custom object (called Notka) with prototype.constructor and with some methods also added with prototype, then im pushing it into array of objects, then converting array into json object and saving it on external server. So far so good.

When im getting it from external server as json and converting it to array of objects name property of object is lost and im getting anonymous object that dont recognize their methods. I have a few ideas to avoid converting arrays to objects and viceversa and to avoid all this mess but im asking out of curiosity, is there a way to preserve name of object or to change name of anonymous object.

I tried creating new object of my custom type, like:

```
var nt = new Notka(); // my custom object
nt = tab[index]; // tab is a array containing objects fetched from external sever
```

but it does not work, newly created Notka has constructor.name Notka but when ill assign object i have anonymous object again.

thank You in advance for any answer :)

Kuba

Comment: I'd think your server code would be relevant here. How exactly are you saving it?

Comment: i think that name is lost in converting process, im using node.js express framework and XMLHTTPRequest with POST method. It is as simple and standard as possible :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can't serialize a JSON object and preserve the name or methods of a function (which is what Notka is, not a simple object). When you are saving this object to a database, it is converted into a string first. What your database gets is the output from `JSON.stringify( nt );`. So when it comes back to you and gets parsed, it's missing everything except what is allowed in the [JSON standard](http://www.json.org/), which is not the same as JavaScript, node.js or otherwise. It's much simpler and only allows certain datatypes (basically plain objects, numbers, strings, and arrays).

It sounds like you probably want to modify your constructor so that you can do something like this instead:

```
var nt = new Notka( tab[index] );
```

If you do simply `nt = tab[index]` you are destroying the reference to the original Notka object you created earlier.

so maybe

```
var Notka = function( obj ) {
    for ( var i in obj )
        this[i] = obj[i];
};

Notka.prototype.multiply = function( times ) {
    return this.someProperty * times;
};

var tab = [{
    someProperty: 4,
    another: "notka!"
}, {
    someProperty: 15,
    another: "lalalala"
}];

var nt = new Notka( tab[0] );
nt.multiply( 5 );

// 20
```

Comment: Ty that was a solution, still im a bit confused how to use prototypes and how should oop in javascript look.

Comment: The most important thing to keep in mind is that JSON and JavaScript are not the same thing--JSON is a language-agnostic serialization format (like XML) that happens to map well to JavaScript data structures. IMO, the most powerful features of JavaScript are its functional programming features, none of which are possible with JSON alone (as you've discovered). And, yes, prototype inheritance is a different way of thinking about OOP, and it really needs to be thought of **on its own terms**--do yourself a favor and _never_ try to understand it using Java as a point of reference.